# ggplot title not working?

Tags: r, ggplot2, title

I'm using the ggplot2 library in R and trying to put a title on my ggplot but it's telling me the ggtitle function doesn't exist!

This is my code:

```
p <- ggplot (data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(shape= 21, fill= "blue", colour= "black", size=2) +
  xlab("X Value") + ylab("Y Value") +
  geom_smooth(method= "lm", se= FALSE,  colour= "red", formula=y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-SE, ymax=y+SE), width=.9)
p
```

I tried this but it isn't working:

```
    p <- ggplot (data, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_point(shape= 21, fill= "blue", colour= "black", size=2) +
      xlab("X Value") + ylab("Y Value") +
      geom_smooth(method= "lm", se= FALSE,  colour= "red", formula=y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE)) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-SE, ymax=y+SE), width=.9) + 
      ggtitle( "title")
    p
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What version of ggplot2 package you have? Function ggtitle() was implemented since version 0.9.2.

Comment: I realized I was on an older version, I just updated it and the ggtitle works now too. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using  ggplot2 < 0.9.2. Try this instead:

```
p + opts(title="Title text").
```